# objeto dentro de objeto javascript

Tags: javascript

Podem me dar um exemplo básico de como é feito conforme na imagem abaixo?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso aninhar as informações obtida através da função `obter_conta_me` através [deste código(clicar aqui)](https://pastebin.com/raw/hPyKck6D), antes da linha `$('[name="id"]').val(tbl_lancamento.id);`

Comment: Fica melhor para o pessoal que poderá te ajudar se houver o código ao invés de imagem. E como é feito o que? Não ficou claro pra mim o que você quer..

Comment: @LucasCosta, eu atualizei o código, pode me ajudar agora ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muito simples, basta declarar um objeto dentro de outro.

```
var conta = {
  ag: '0000',
  banco: {
    cod: 033,
    id: 9,
    nome: 'Santander'
  }
}
```

Documentação simples: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno!!